# Joi form validation: removing displayed errors

Tags: javascript, validation, svelte, joi

[Here is a link to codesandbox example (Svelte)](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mopsa-clvmyp?file=/App.svelte). It represents a trivial register from being validated with `Joi`. The issue I'm facing is with clearing Joi validation error messages. I'm recording them in `errors` object, keys named by the input name (`email`, `password`, `passwordConfirm`).

Validations happens via function attached to form `on:input`

```js
      const validate = async e => {
        const fields = { [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
        try {
          errors[Object.keys(fields)[0]] = null;
          await registerSchema.validateAsync(
            { ...fields },
            { abortEarly: false, allowUnknown: true }
          );
        } catch (err) {
          errors[Object.keys(fields)[0]] = err;
        }
      };
```

Its crude but it *mostly* works. It clears `email` and `password` errors alright but whatever I do `passwordConfirm` persists.

I don't think the issue is with my Joi schema:

```js
export const registerSchema = Joi.object({
  email: Joi.string().email({ tlds: { allow: false } }),
  password: Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,30}$")).trim(),
  passwordConfirm: Joi.string().valid(Joi.ref("password")).trim()
});
```

Am pretty sure that the bug hides somewhere in the `validate` function itself but - for the death of me - I can find it. I would appreciate couple of hints here.

[Again, example can be seen on codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mopsa-clvmyp?file=/App.svelte)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is indeed in your validate function. When you build your `fields` object, the only key you add to it is the currently active input:
`const fields = { [e.target.name]: e.target.value };`, meaning that when you compare `passwordConfirm` to `Joi.ref('password')` in your schema, the latter is always an empty value because there is no `password` key in the object being validated!

One (crude) way around that is to make sure the `password` field is passed into the object being validated when the active input is `passwordConfirm`:

```js
  const validate = async e => {
    const fields = { [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    if (e.target.name === 'passwordConfirm') {
      fields.password = password;
    }
    // console.log(fields); // log object being validated
    try {
      errors[Object.keys(fields)[0]] = null;
      await registerSchema.validateAsync(
        { ...fields },
        { abortEarly: false, allowUnknown: true }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      errors[Object.keys(fields)[0]] = err;
    }
  };
```

Tested in your CodeSandbox and seemed to work as intended.